# A good persistent synchronous queue in python

Tags: python, queue

I don't immediately care about fifo or filo options, but it might be nice in the future..

What I'm looking for a is a nice fast simple way to store (at most a gig of data or tens of millions of entries) on disk that can be get and put by multiple processes.  The entries are just simple 40 byte strings, not python objects.  Don't really need all the functionality of [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html).

I've seen this http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/310105/
It looks simple.  It needs to be upgraded to the new Queue version.

Wondering if there's something better?  I'm concerned that in the event of a power interruption, the entire pickled file becomes corrupt instead of just one record.

Comment: If you know the exact width of your data, a database isn't an unreasonable solution if the latency isn't a problem.  You could use sqlite for a very simple solution.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very old question, but [`persist-queue`](https://pypi.org/project/persist-queue/) seems to be a nice tool for this kind of task.

> persist-queue implements a file-based queue and a serial of
> sqlite3-based queues. The goals is to achieve following requirements:
>
> - Disk-based: each queued item should be stored in disk in case of any crash.
> - Thread-safe: can be used by multi-threaded producers and multi-threaded consumers.
> - Recoverable: Items can be read after process restart.
> - Green-compatible: can be used in greenlet or eventlet environment.
>
> By default, persist-queue use pickle object serialization module to
> support object instances. Most built-in type, like int, dict, list are
> able to be persisted by persist-queue directly, to support customized
> objects, please refer to Pickling and unpickling extension
> types(Python2) and Pickling Class Instances(Python3)

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/). It's not pure python, as it uses RabbitMQ as a backend, but it's reliable, persistent and distributed, and, all in all, far better then using files or database in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

I think that [PyBSDDB](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb_doc/) is what you want. You can choose a queue as the access type. PyBSDDB is a Python module based on [Oracle Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html).
It has synchronous access and can be accessed from different processes although I don't know if that is possible from the Python bindings. About multiple processes writing to the db I found [this thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=511499).

Answer (score -3):

Using files is not working?...

Use a journaling file system to recover from power interruptions. That's their purpose.

Comment: journaling helps to maintain consistency of metadata (!) not data. It is very easy to lose your data using just plain files.